# Install Android ADT in Eclipse Show errors

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I'm trying to install Android ADT in Eclipse it gives errors.Plese some one help me to resolve this issue.I had been stick here for a long time.
this is the shown error.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. 
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)

Comment: Use Android Studio, Eclipse is deprecated for android development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Android Studio as Eclipse is no longer supported by Google for Android development. This link will provide you with all you need to get started with Android development using Android Studio. The UI is similar but this is now the official IDE for Android development.

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

But if you must use Eclipse

You should remove old adt before install new one.

1. Eclipse-->Help-->About Eclipse---->Installation Details
2. Select - Android DDMS, ADT, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Native
3. Development Tools, Android TraceView and Tracer for OpenGL ES
   packages.
4. Uninstall all the plugins selected above.
5. Restart Eclipse
6. Install ADT from update site -
   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/